# How do I use HttpClient to call a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using the ServiceModel class library.
In.NET Core3.1, an error was reported that I could not load the ServiceModel class library.

I want to implement a dynamic library that calls the WCF service dynamically, without adding a reference in the VS.

Since the user of the class library packaged is using Net Core3.1.
I would like to ask if it is possible to make dynamic calls to the WCF service.
HttpClient would be the best option.

```
public static T CreateServiceByUrl<T>(string url)
{
    return CreateServiceByUrl<T>(url, "basicHttpBinding");///Unable to load the class library
}

public static T CreateServiceByUrl<T>(string url, string bing)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) throw new NotSupportedException("This url is not Null or Empty!");
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(url);
        Binding binding = CreateBinding(bing);
        ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, address);
        return factory.CreateChannel();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("创建服务工厂出现异常.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not C code. Please review your tags.

Comment: is C# code sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use SOAP UI to get the SOAP requests from the WSDL.
Then modify at runtime these XML requests and POST the message to the .svc with the application/soap+xml content type.
That's how it is usually done from languages where there is no native SOAP wrapper or proxy generator.